# How to make a master-detail form based on complex views updatable

Tags: forms, oracle

I'm creating a form with  one-master-two-detail data blocks, each of them based a complex view(3-5 tables) and have multiple rows on its screen.

Some fields on the mater and detail screen need updatable. How can I do updating on the same master-detail screen, without adding another form screen based on that single table for update.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the direction for me. I created the triggers and the detail form updatable now but not the master. When compiling  I got FRM-30100: Block must have at least one primary key item. Block: INDS_CCR_MANAG_MAIN FRM-30100: Block must have at least one primary key item. Block: INDS_CCR_MANAG_DETAIL2    The master and detail forms update the same customer table that has a PK on it. The detail's view has two base tables and the 2nd one no key on it. The master's view has 5 base tables. Three of them are native Oracle EBS tables, no PK on them. How can I fix the bug? Thanks a lot.

Comment: On the frontend I got ORA-01779 from master update. Detail form OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a ON-UPDATE trigger on each block you need, manually updating each table you want to.

Comment: After Primary Key on Property Palette in each PK item in its block is set as 'Yes', FRM-30100 error was gone, but the master form is still not updatable, error OAR-01779 -cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table. Please help, expert! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check in your block properties:
- Database Data Block is set to "Yes"?
- Query Data Source Type is set to which option?
- Query Data Source Name has what value?

Comment: This new errror means you are trying to update a view. You should check if all your blocks have ON-UPDATE triggers and if their statements are only updating tables instead of views.

Comment: Hi Elisa, Good news! The problem was fixed by updating the table instead of view. Only some views are updatable, but tables are guaranteed. Thanks again, Elisa. But wait... the project comes out a new request: The users want to have a control on the master form--show all records, open records or closed records that can be based a column of a base table. How can do it? This is another question--Should I post it as a new one?

Comment: You're welcome! I guess you should open another question, describing it with details.
ps: my name is Elias, not Elisa - lol

Comment: Hi Elias, I've recreated the new question with detailed information on it. Thank you so much for your help! And sorry for the typo on your name.

Comment: Elias, could you please post some tips for my new question? Thank you for your help.